# ILogger<T>? defaulting to null vs ILogger<T> defaulting to NullLogger<T>

Tags: c#, .net-core, nullable-reference-types

Take the following two classes:

```
public class PersonA
{
    private readonly ILogger<PersonA> _logger;

    public PersonA() : this(new NullLogger<PersonA>())
    {}
    
    public PersonA(ILogger<PersonA> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("SomeMethod invoked");
    }
}

public class PersonB
{
    private readonly ILogger<PersonB>? _logger;

    public PersonB(ILogger<PersonB>? logger = null)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _logger?.LogDebug("SomeMethod invoked");
    }
}
```

The way that `ILogger<T>` is passed is very similar in both and both approaches work, but is there any reason why you'd favour `ILogger<T>?` defaulting to `null` over two ctors one defaulting to `NullLogger<T>` and ensuring that `_logger` is never null or vice-versa?

Are any differences in performance?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Questions should not be opinion based. Are you asking about performance ? Are you trying to understand which design is better ? What is the criteria are you using to compare these alternatives design ? Are you facing an issue of any kind with one of them ?

Comment: I would say that unless you are writing a very-very-very critical high-performance code the difference is to negligible to actually care.

Comment: @EnricoMassone the first two, as is stated in the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by one comment, there is so little difference in tearms of performance and object allocation that I would actually avoid to compare these two approaches in tearms of performance.

I would instead suggest the following considerations:

- having two constructors is worst in terms of design. That will make creating your object harder, because the object creator has to choose between the two and have to understand the different semantic. It is much better having one and only one way to create an object: that's simpler and there is no ambiguity about the way the object should be created
- as long as possible I would avoid handling `null` values. Code using objects that can potentially be `null` is harder to maintain, because if you accidentally forget the `?` operator when you refactor your code you will get a `NullReferenceException` at runtime. You would need to write and maintain additional unit tests for the `null` case, in order to be sure you didn't forget a `?` somewhere in your code.

Based on these two points, a better design is the following:

1. have a class with only one constructor
2. do not allow the `_logger` field to be nullable, that is it's type should be `ILogger<Person>` instead of `ILogger<Person>?`. In cases when you don't care about logging, use the *null object pattern* and inject an instance of `NullLogger<Person>` in the constructor (instead of using a `null` reference).

As a final note do not instantiate `NullLogger<T>`. Use, instead, the [`NullLogger<T>.Instance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions.nulllogger-1.instance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) static field. By doing so, you will access to a shared cached instance of the class and you will avoid to allocate a new object (it's fine to do so for stateless classes like `NullLogger<T>`). This is good in tearms of memory usage and garbage collector pressure.

Final design of the class is the following:

```
public class Person
{
    private readonly ILogger<Person> _logger;

    public Person(ILogger<Person> logger)
    {
        // guard against null
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("SomeMethod invoked");
    }
}

// if you don't care about logging
var person = new Person(NullLogger<Person>.Instance);
```

Comment: I mostly agree with your analysis... except for one thing: if you're writing a library and you want to give the consumer the ability to log, but also allow them to choose whether to log or not ... you're now forcing them to have a reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll` so that they can pass `NullLogger<Person>.Instance`, else they can't use your library.

Comment: So in order to preserve just one ctor and remove nullability on `_logger` then you need to have a ctor that accepts a `ILogger<Person>? logger` and use `_logger = logger ? NullLogger<Person>.Instance`

Comment: That's another possibility: make the logger parameter nullable, but leave the field non nullable and default to NullableLogger<Person>.Instance when a null reference is provided to the constructor. I get your point, but that's probably not so critical: if you write a library which reference Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and some client code references your library, they get an implicit reference on Microsoft.Extensions.Logging too. So, they will have access to the types needed for the public api of your types.

Comment: When you design a type which requires a parameter of type ILogger<T> in its public api, you have already opinionated the way you intend to log from your library. Client code using your library needs to accept your opinionated way of doing logging and adhere to it. This is not a problem, because the current .NET ecosystem is already strongly opinionated with regards to logging in using Microsft.Extensions.Logging as the standard logging system. If the users of your library are used to write and consume .NET core libraries, they have already accepted the usage of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Comment: To summarize I think that opinionnating the logging infrastructure to ILogger<T> is not a problem and I would design the type by requesting a non nullable instance of ILogger<Person> as the constructor parameter. I would leave the null check in the constructor in place. If you want to explore ways of logging from an application without requiring the injection of a logger from the client code, take a look at the diagnostic source library (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/DiagnosticSourceUsersGuide.md)

Comment: Here https://andrewlock.net/logging-using-diagnosticsource-in-asp-net-core/#when-to-use-diagnosticsource-vs-ilogger- you can find some guidelines to decide between using ILogger<T> and diagnostic source. Diagnostic source is more for instrumentation needs. In practice I have never used it and I always log stuff in libraries by using ILogger<T> with the appropriate log level.